# how to make translation in contents of list item on scroll?

Tags: android

have you ever seen BRIEFING? thats a news app in samsung devices.that app has a special list.look at this images...

[befre scroll image](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8204865650/Screenshot_%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B5_%DB%B0%DB%B8_%DB%B0%DB%B7_%DB%B2%DB%B1_%DB%B1%DB%B1_%DB%B4%DB%B9.png)
...
....
and after scrolling, you could see ...
....
...
[after scroll image](http://s3.picofile.com/file/8204865550/Screenshot_%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B5_%DB%B0%DB%B8_%DB%B0%DB%B7_%DB%B2%DB%B1_%DB%B1%DB%B1_%DB%B3%DB%B5.png)

my question is: how can i make a list such this one?
when you move the scroll,you can see that the image of the item,moves smoothly inside of the item of the list.

could you help me??

Comment: the different scroll speeds is called "parallax effect". Try Google about it and try to write some code, then ask here. PS.: I will be easier to do with RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallax HeaderView
here is github  tutorial

https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

One more thing At the end of the tutorial make sure you replace actionbar with toolbar.

modify your style xml to

```js
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

good luck.